# No errors but jQuery code does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

Could someone say what the matter is? At first I have load jQuery Waypoints (http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) then included the code you could see after the text.
I need fadeIn effect on images when scrolling down the page but nothing heppen at all. I found this solution here at Stack Overflow - [JQuery fade-in a div when user scrolls to that div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367731/jquery-fade-in-a-div-when-user-scrolls-to-that-div)
And here is the link where I am trying to do my solution - http://layot.prestatrend.com
Thanks!

```
// by default your element will be hidden
$('.ajax_block_product').hide();
// call waypoint plugin
$('.ajax_block_product').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    // do your fade in here
    $(this).fadeIn();
}, {
   offset: function() {
       // The bottom of the element is in view
       return $.waypoints('viewportHeight') - $(this).outerHeight();
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you forget to paste in the code?

Comment: You've supplied very little in terms of actual information to help you. We could look at plug in pages, past questions, and jquery references forever and never even come close to guessing what's wrong with **your** code.

Comment: Try the following, it should work.

Comment: No, I could not. Sorry... Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. I do but this error do not disappears.

Comment: @Anton Then try again; everyone else can post code.

Comment: I have updated my post with code. See, please...

Comment: Hm, I see my code work but not I need exactly. It is fadeIn images when page is loading but no fadeIn effect when scroll down the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery hide function sets `display:none` on an element.  Elements with `display:none` don't report the correct `offset`.  Try initially setting the opacity to 0 or visibility to hidden instead.