# Fade in while scrolling down. How?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

Bro, I am looking for such fade in effect for images while scrolling down the page like this - http://www.google.com/tv/index.html or this http://www.stellamccartney.com/default/shop-products/Dresses
I have heard about Lazy Load plugin, it is loading images while scrolling but I need just fading them in. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've got a link to a good plugin for this on my blog: http://webdesignrevolution.tumblr.com/post/16106467838/create-killer-scrolling-websites-with-scrollorama

Comment: Scrollorama (http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/) yes? It is possible with a help of it fading in elements while scrolling down the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can quite easily do this yourself.

1. set display: none with jquery for all images (or the images you want to run the effect on), that are not within the $(window).innerHeight (get document scrolling offset with $(window).scrollTop() )
2. add an onscroll listener for the document $(document).onscroll() and use $(element).fadeIn on the image when it scrolls into the viewport.

Do better illustrate the way to script this, the following script is rather a logical concept than a copy/paste template ^^. I haven't tested this, but it should be a decent guideline.

assuming your images are properly classed like this:

```
<img class="classForImagesToApplyTheEffectOn" src="…" />
```

your script could read something like this

```
$('.ajax_block_product').each(function(index, el) {

    tiles = $(el);
    a = $(el).offset().top + $(el).height();
    b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if (a > b) $(el).fadeTo(0,0);

    $(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
        tiles.each(function(i) {
            a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
            b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: O, man, I am not good in jQuery, could you explain it more detail? By the way, here is the link where I am workin on http://layot.prestatrend.com see the images? I need such effect for them, help, please! :)

Comment: added an example script, which should be more or less accurate.

Comment: $(this).fadeIn(2000); and $(this).offset(); refer to the "window" element, not the classForImagesToApplyTheEffectOn

Comment: @KyleMacey: dang, you are right. thx! should've read the code twice before hitting the submit button.

Comment: I have such error at Chrome - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined :(

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready( function() {
 $('.ajax_block_product').each(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var imgOffset = $('.ajax_block_product').offset();
        if( imgOffset.top - $(document).scrollTop() < $(window).innerHeight() )
            $('.ajax_block_product').fadeIn(2000);
    });
});
});
</script>`

Comment: Oh, I replaced $(window).innerHeight() with $(window).height() - but when page load now you can not see images untill you start scrolling - http://layot.prestatrend.com is there any solution?

Comment: Could you see this solution -http://stackoverflow.com/a/5368165/1186095 ? But the matter is still so - Images do not show when page is loading...

Comment: Drachenviech - here is what I need exactly - stackoverflow.com/a/5368165/1186095 but when page is load no images are shown only if start scrolling, is there a way to show images in viewport when page is load?

Comment: you have to modify the "$(this).css('display', 'none');" part to only hide the images which are initially not in the viewport.

Comment: Drachenviech, but how to do this with a help of jQuery? It is very difficult?

Comment: @Anton: see edited solution. I did not test it however and you might need to tweak a little here and there.

Comment: Anybody give me whole example of this ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but you can now achieve this via the jQuery appear:

> https://plugins.jquery.com/appear/

Check out the demo at:

> http://morr.github.io/appear.html