# FadeOut div when scrolling horizontally

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein, fadeout

I want to slowly fade out a div using JQuery when I start scrolling horizontally, and then Fade back in when I go back to 0 in the horizontal axis. So I have this:

```
    <div id="hider">Content</div>
```

And then the script:

```
    $(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
    if($('body').scrollLeft() == 0)
    $("#hider").fadeIn();
    else 
    $("#hider").fadeOut();
    });
    });
```

and on the CSS

I have:

```
    #hider {
position: absolute;
left: 34px;
display: none;
    }
```

I saw this solution in a similar thread, but I can't get it to work.The div #hider just keeps blinking on and off as I scroll and never stops blinking

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting a tag not an id:

Do this: add a `#` like this:

```
$("#hider").fadeIn();
```

see this : http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/  and  http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5367731/235710) for what you are trying to do.